# Check if a player is moving or not

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm creating a plugin for an event, this event is just: when you stop moving, you loose. I created everything, but my check to know if a player moves or not doesn't work:

I tried to make an array and when a player move event it's added, but it doesn't work,

```
@EventHandler
public static void OnPlayerMoov(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
    if(!playerHaveMooved.contains(e.getPlayer())) {
        playerHaveMooved.add(e.getPlayer());
    }
}

public static boolean isMoving(Player p){
    System.out.println(Respawn.playerHaveMooved.contains(p));
    return Respawn.playerHaveMooved.contains(p);
}
```

I tried to use velocity; it doesn't work,

```
public static boolean isMoving(Player p){
    return (p.getVelocity().length() == 0);
}
```

It doesn't work. It kills me when I am moving.

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Can you show some block of code?

Comment: What do you mean with "don't work" ? Also, can you show the code of what you tried ?

Comment: Show my edit pls

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect ! I will make an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first don't work because you just check if the player already move a time, which will always be true.

The second about velocity check only if player get knockbacked for example.

### First solution

Save last time of move, and check each few time if it stop move.

In this example, I will force player to move each seconds.

```java
private final HashMap<Player, Long> timeMove = new HashMap<>(); // map for data

@Eventhandler
public void onMove(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
   timeMove.put(e.getPlayer(), System.currentTimeMillis()); // update last move
}

public void startChecking(JavaPlugin pl) {
   pl.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskTimer(pl, () -> {
      long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
      for(Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
         long last = timeMove.getOrDefault(p, 0);
         long diff = current - last;
         if(diff > 1000) { // 1000 = second
            // player don't move
         }
      }
   }, 20, 20);
}
```

### Second solution

Check each X time from last and current location

```java
private final HashMap<Player, Location> lastLoc = new HashMap<>(); // map for data

public void startChecking(JavaPlugin pl) {
   pl.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskTimer(pl, () -> {
      for(Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
         Location lastPlayerLoc = lastLoc.get(p); // get loc, or keep null if not registered
         if(lastPlayerLoc != null) {
            double distance = lastPlayerLoc.distance(p.getLocation());
            if(distance == 0.0) {
               // here the player don't move
               continue; // go to next player
            }
         }
         lastLoc.put(p, p.getLocation()); // update loc
      }
   }, 20, 20);
}
```